# Vetur "Cannot find name 'reactive'" with Nuxt 3 and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, vetur

I use Vue with Vetur every day at work and have my Vetur setup for Vue 3 but I have never actually used TS on the front-end before so I'm unsure if this is a Vetur issue or not.

I'm following along with a Nuxt 3 tutorial and the instructor has the same code verbatim with no issues but my editor is telling me that it doesn't recognize `reactive`. My understanding is that with Nuxt/Composition API/TypeScript, you shouldn't need to `import {reactive} from 'vue'`.

If I do import `reactive`, the options variable appears to be unused as far as the syntax highlighting goes.

The app will compile just fine, but I'm getting the warnings/problems. I sifted through the Vetur options and didn't see anything to address this. I tried adding a Nuxt extension but that didn't seem to help.

The errors are:

```bash
 Cannot find name 'reactive'.Vetur(2304)
❌ Cannot find name 'reactive'.ts(2304)
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Please post code, no images, so people can copy and paste it.

Comment: About extention for Nuxt 3 best is Volar.

Comment: @Mises - I didn't include the code snippet because the code is 100% valid and I was trying to point out the syntax highlighting issue. But thank you. I have Volar and Vetur both installed and I modified the settings, I'm a full-time Vue developer and have a lot of opinions on how I want them to work. I just disabled Vetur for this workspace and now it's perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Vetur might be not yet ready to work with Nuxt 3.